# Database version is higher than SSMS and throwing error when attempted to create table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, visual-studio-2017

I have installed VS 2017. After that I have installed SQL Server 2014.

Whenever I create a DB using SSMS and attempt to create a table it returns the following error:

> This backend version is not supported to design database diagrams or
>   tables. (MS Visual Database Tools).

When creating the database using SSMS the compatibility level has no value to select from.

Version of the SQL Server is 2017 and version of SSMS is 2014. How do I resolve this?

As there any way to use SQL Server 2017 with SSMS 2014?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AS MSDN Blog [Here](https://forums.asp.net/t/2110197.aspx?+This+backend+version+is+not+supported+to+design+database+diagrams+or+tables+MS+Visual+Database+Tools+)  Use the SSMS version designed for your database version. You can use the command `select @@version;` to check which version of SQL Server you are actually using.  Update your `SSMS` to the latest version and try.  You may have the latest version of SQL Server and older version of `SSMS`.

To Download the latest SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx

For your further ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146474/the-backend-version-is-not-supported-to-design-database-diagrams-or-tables

Comment: is there any way to use sql server 2017 with ssms 2014?

Comment: @TheDeparted Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @AaronBertrand i know now that it cant be done.

Comment: I believe you can use T-SQL script directly in the lower versioned SSMS to operate in higher-versioned database engine. In my case, I am currently SSMS 2016 and I can connect to my SQL Server 2017 and run scripts directly to create tables/databases in SQL Server 2017.

Comment: @jyao Yes, I think that is key - the compatibility error isn't with SSMS per se, its with *the table designer GUI* in SSMS. Executing `CREATE TABLE` commands from SSMS 2014 against SQL 2017, although more tedious, should absolutely work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to resolve your issue, you will have to use a newer version of SMSS than your DB. It's backward compatible.

Comment: is there any way to use sql server 2017 with ssms 2014?